# A user so nice, I got listed twice!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-score

The top users lists have been static for a few days, so I was pleased to see that the data has been refreshed sometime in the last few minutes (currently 11:20 PM EST).

A weird side-effect, and something transient, but look at my view of [this top user list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers) at 11:18 PM:

[image: screenshot]

Is this a bug? By definition, yes, since a user can observe incorrect behaviour. A low priority to fix, due to its transient nature. Go ahead - tell me it's unreproducible - I'm just going to keep reloading the page until I see it again...

BUT... Really, really cool! <sub><sup>For me.</sup></sub>

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: [Something very similar has happened before...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99502/175248) likely not in the same spot, but this is very familiar.  Also, no repro; may have been a temporal thing.

Comment: Maybe a side-effect of [Eventual Consistency](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)?

Comment: I'd personally be inclined to blame caching. You're only showing up once when I look.

Comment: @DennisMeng I thought because maybe they cache the list and then when someone moves up they relocate him in the cache (and if they didn't find they insert him, which is your case), instead of re-creating the list. In a second thought this is a total bug even if my assuming is correct.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/

Comment: It's not the number of times they show up in a list that makes gods, but to be the first in every list.

Comment: Congratulations!  (and enjoy your silver:) )

Comment: Thanks all, for the comments. Most illuminating to know that similar events have occurred before, thanks Makoto. Hans, I enjoyed the blog as well, it provided some insight into what's going on behind the curtain.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Given this isn't reliably reproducible, I will chalk it down to a harmless race somewhere.